# Should one redefined (or cancel) default layout for autofilled inputs?

Tags: input-fields, input, best-practice, chrome

The yellow background of the input we see on the screenshot below is due the way Chrome renders autofilled inputs by default. Technically, I can got rid of this by introducing a bunch of cumbersome CSS rules, but the real question is - should I?

[image]

Can we claim that the default visual indication of autofilled inputs is widely used, well known and accepted to that extend that it should not be customized at all?

If it's still an acceptable UX practice, what would be better  - to god rid of autofill styling completely (in favor of layouts that exist in application) - or should one, while getting rid of default autofill layouts, still come up with some alternative visual markers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to overcome visual changes applied on top of your design by the browser or any number of addons is a cat and mouse game that you will likely never win.

I'd therefore recommend to not attempt to control it, and just let it do whatever it does.

If you think about the user's perspective on this, they are used to every website/app they go to having these yellow boxes for auto filled values. If your site is now the only one that doesn't do this, your site is now inconsistent with their expectations.